# numpy/ENH: RMS function #12579,

Tags: numpy

In [numpy/ENH: RMS function #12579](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12579), someone says that "the square is in the wrong place" in:

```
def rms(array):
   return np.sqrt(np.mean(array ** 2)))
```

except for a redundant bracket I can't find anything wrong in the code snippet?

Comment: They meant that the calculation is wrong (I'm not sure about that), not that the syntax is wrong or the code will give an error.

Comment: The original version was incorrect, but it was later fixed.  You can see the change by clicking on the "edited" pulldown menu.

Comment: I am voting to close this post, considering the edit made on the github issue linked, the question has become pretty moot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm satisfied. How do I close the post?